# Sending HAML emails with Pony

Tags: sinatra, haml, pony

Sinatra 1.2.6 / Haml 3.1.2 and Pony

I am getting "wrong number of arguments error (0 for 1)" which points to

sinatra/base.rb

```
def haml(template, options={}, locals={})
  render :haml, template, options, locals
end
```

I am sending :html_body => (haml :html_email) to Pony

Any help would be very much appreciated!

M.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work in Sinatra 1.2.6, Haml 3.1.3 and Pony 1.3.
Although I would use haml(:test) instead of (haml :test)

test.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'pony'
require 'haml'

set :views, Proc.new { root }

get '/send' do
    options = {
    :to => 'user@gmail.com',
    :from => 'user@gmail.com',
    :subject => 'Test',
    :body => 'Test Text',
    :html_body => (haml :test),
    :via => :smtp,
    :via_options => {
      :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port => 587,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :user_name => 'login',
      :password => 'password',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :domain => 'HELO'
    }
  }

  Pony.mail(options)
end
```

test.haml:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{ :content => "text/html; charset=utf-8", :"http-equiv" => "Content-Type" }
    %title Test
  %body
    %h1 Test
    %p Test content
```